# How do I cast a String type as double in HQL order by clause

Tags: hibernate, casting, sql-order-by, hql

I have a table structure as depicted in the below picture:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

As you can see from the image, the `fieldValue` is not of a specific data type.
I am trying to fetch rows, CAST and sort them as below using HQL and it doesn't work.[image]

`select Field field from Field where field.fieldInfo.name like 'Cost' order by CAST(field.fieldValue as double)`

However, I get an exception saying about precision in Hibernate.

**P.S:** The reason I was given for such a table structure is the field names are dynamic in nature and can be of multitude of data types. So it was implented as varchar in the database and casted in SQL query.

Comment: I understand this table structure is kind of bizarre. I have to revamp the entire architecture to find a original fix. I intend to do this probably as a long term solution, However, what would be the best possible solution as of now?

Comment: What is the exception? Show us the full stack trace.